# OpenGL share textures across multiple processes

Tags: java, opengl, memory, textures, lwjgl

I'm currently trying to create a mod for Minecraft, which can play videos from an url ingame.

I use the library VLCJ (a JAVA bridge for LibVLC). It encodes the video and provides a buffer, which can be used to upload a texture (via OpenGL) and render it.

This works absolutely fine, but problems appear as soon as multiple videos are played simultaneously. VCLJ suggests to only have one player per process. So the only solution is to create a new process for each player. The problem is to transfer the render data from the new process back to the original one.

OpenGL (lwjgl) provides shared memory solutions ([source](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/OpenCL_OpenGL_Memory_Sharing.html)), so my question is:

Does this work across multiple process?
**Is it possible for the player to upload a texture, which than can be used by the other process (Minecraft) to render it?**

The benefit would be no need to transfer a lot of data via websockets, or other interprocess communication possibilities.